# Learn Python the Hard Way ex 46

Tags: python, module, pip, setup.py

I'm at a complete loss as to how to complete exercise 46's http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html required quiz. Making the directories in the way explained by the author was very clear and I even got the nosetests to run OK, but I'm at a complete loss for the Required Quiz. I'm supposed to make my own module(?) and install it using pip. AFAIK, to do that I would do

```
pip install setup.py
```

while in Powershell but I have no idea where inside of the 'skeleton' to put any of the scripts, modules that I'm supposed to write -- or even what they are supposed to contain. If anyone could help clarify what the meaning of all this is in a newbie friendly way I'd appreciate it very much.

Also, when I try to do

```
pip install setup.py
```

from the skeleton folder I get an error from Powershell saying:

```
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement setup.py
Cleaning up...
No distributions at all found for setup.py
Storing debug log for failure in C:\Users\Owner\pip\pip.log
```

Many thanks for reading and helping in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `python setup.py` or `C:\PythonXX\python.exe setup.py`

The difference is that if you want to install a module, lets say `numpy`. You do

```
pip install numpy
```

which downloads it, and runs `python setup.py`

So if you have something downloaded then you will need to read about "how to install downloaded stuff with pip".